# Add child-process to cgroup?

Tags: linux

Following the advice in [my previous question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/274350/99202) here I currently have a Rust-binary that gets executed by my main-app using [std::process::Command](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html).

The executed binary first gets validated by a hash.

The main-app should not have any limitations. But the executed child-binary should not be able to access network or denied files, this I have achieved with AppArmor.

Now I also want to limit the memory usage and cpu usage of the child binary. I have made cgroups with the following commands:

```
sudo cgcreate -g cpu,memory:rustserver
sudo cgset -r memory.max=150000000 rustserver
sudo cgset -r cpu.max=25000 rustserver
```

Now I have a issue. I could execute the rust-server with `sudo cgexec -g cpu,memory:rustserver target/debug/rust-api` but then the child process which is executed with `std::process::Command` and actually needs to be limited arent included.

I could execute `sudo cgexec` in my Rust code, but for obvious reasons I do not want to give the child process sudo rights.

I am wondering how I can get all instances of the child-binary into the cgroups?

Maybe this is a approach?

1. Make a new user.
2. Give this user permission to write to /sys/fs/cgroups/... without the need of sudo.
3. So it can write the pid of the child-process to there.

Answer (score 0):

This is my current solution:

```
watch -n 5 'sudo cgclassify $(pgrep -x python-executor | tr "\n" " ")'
```

Execute cgclassify every 5 seconds to add the python-executor to the correct cgroup based on `etc/cgrules.conf`.